# courtesy of sweeping legislation

Tags: phrase-usage

Does "courtesy of sweeping legislation" mean "as a result of sweeping legislation"?

> As a global pandemic brought life in many cities to a halt this year, the ground beneath Hong Kong shifted at an astonishing speed, **courtesy of sweeping legislation** imposed by Beijing in June that outlawed opposing China in any form, on any platform, anywhere in the world.

> [Source: CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/12/17/asia/hong-kong-exiles-and-inmates-dst-hnk-intl/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Another less obscure idiom would be "**thanks to** sweeping legislation", which suggests the origin of this sense of "courtesy of"

Comment: Are both "courtesy of" and "thanks to" more euphemistic than "due to" or "because of"?   Thank you.

Comment: @NewPlanet I would not call them  euphemisms. They are figures of speech. "Thanks to" at least is a sufficiently common fixed phrase that might be called an idiom. I think "courtesy of" may derive from the once common radio (and later TV) sponsorship msg: "This program brought to you **courtesy of** XYZ soap." meaning that XYZ paid for the program.